# Unable to connect to Azure DB using JDBC with ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal

Tags: jdbc, azure-active-directory, azure-sql-database, azure-ad-msal, mssql-jdbc

I'm trying to connect to an Azure DB via JDBC using authentication mode *ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal*.

Connection string: jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;Database=abcd;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;

Used Java components:

- mssql-jdbc-11.1.1.jre8-preview.jar
- msal4j-1.11.3.jar
- oauth2-oidc-sdk-9.22.1.jar
- json-smart-2.4.7.jar

When trying to connect, the attempt fails with the following error:

```
2022-04-28 15:23:50 INFO  - Connecting to Source Database jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;Database=abcd;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal; ...
2022-04-28 15:23:50 INFO  - Connecting to Source JDBC data source jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;Database=abcd;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal; ...
2022-04-28 15:23:51 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:51 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:51 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:51 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:51 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:51 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:52 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:52 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:53 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:53 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:54 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:54 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:55 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:55 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:56 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:56 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:57 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:57 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:23:59 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:23:59 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:24:00 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:24:00 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:24:01 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:24:01 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:24:02 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:24:02 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:24:03 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:24:03 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:24:04 DEBUG - SkipCache set to false. Attempting cache lookup
2022-04-28 15:24:04 DEBUG - Cache lookup failed: Token not found in the cache
2022-04-28 15:24:04 ERROR - Error establishing database connection to Source DB (URL: jdbc:sqlserver://xxx.database.windows.net:1433;Database=abcd;Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal;)
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Failed to authenticate the user yyy in Active Directory (Authentication=ActiveDirectoryServicePrincipal). com/nimbusds/common/contenttype/ContentType
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:240)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getSqlFedAuthTokenPrincipal(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:97)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.getFedAuthToken(SQLServerConnection.java:5440)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.onFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:5388)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.processFedAuthInfo(SQLServerConnection.java:5275)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSTokenHandler.onFedAuthInfo(tdsparser.java:305)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:128)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSParser.parse(tdsparser.java:37)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.sendLogon(SQLServerConnection.java:6262)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.logon(SQLServerConnection.java:4880)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.access$100(SQLServerConnection.java:90)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection$LogonCommand.doExecute(SQLServerConnection.java:4818)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.TDSCommand.execute(IOBuffer.java:7601)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.executeCommand(SQLServerConnection.java:3885)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectHelper(SQLServerConnection.java:3331)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.login(SQLServerConnection.java:2923)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connectInternal(SQLServerConnection.java:2763)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerConnection.connect(SQLServerConnection.java:1657)
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDriver.connect(SQLServerDriver.java:1063)
    at com.synabi.dqnconnect2jdbc.util.DriverShim.connect(DriverShim.java:19)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:664)
    at java.sql.DriverManager.getConnection(DriverManager.java:208)
    at com.synabi.dqnconnect2jdbc.Importer.run(Importer.java:484)
    at com.synabi.dqnconnect.App.main(App.java:621)
Caused by: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.RuntimeException: com/nimbusds/common/contenttype/ContentType
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:238)
    ... 23 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com/nimbusds/common/contenttype/ContentType
    at com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException(SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.java:230)
    ... 23 more
```

However, when trying to connect using authentication mode *SqlPassword*, it's working without a problem (different user, of course, but with the same rights). Additionally, the username and password of the Service Principal user works as well when trying to connect using Powershell.

So there seems to be a problem with the JDBC components. Does anyone have any idea how to solve this?

*Edit (for clarification): I've read the official documentation (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/connect/jdbc/connecting-using-azure-active-directory-authentication) and followed the described steps to set up the connection.*

Comment: I'm having the exact same problem except I'm using `authentication=ActiveDirectoryPassword`. I can connect with a different user using `SqlPassword` but get this same ContentType exception and stack trace, right down to the line numbers. Did you ever resolve it?

Comment: @PaulJackson, Yes, I was able to solve it, but didn't post it as an answer because I can't explain in detail what solved it in the end. I was just trying to connect to the database using DataGrip, and DataGrip downloaded a bunch of required jar files automatically. I just tried using the exact same jars, and it finally worked. So it definitely must have been a missing jar, but I don't know which one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got a very similar error and in my case it was a missing jar.

```
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: com/nimbusds/common/contenttype/ContentType
```

is `SQLServerMSAL4JUtils.getCorrectedException`'s way of swallowing the true cause of the exception:

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/nimbusds/common/contenttype/ContentType
    at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.http.HTTPMessage.setContentType(HTTPMessage.java:98)
    at com.nimbusds.oauth2.sdk.http.HTTPRequest.setContentType(HTTPRequest.java:73)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.createOauthHttpRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:41)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.TokenRequestExecutor.executeTokenRequest(TokenRequestExecutor.java:31)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AbstractClientApplicationBase.acquireTokenCommon(AbstractClientApplicationBase.java:128)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.execute(AcquireTokenByAuthorizationGrantSupplier.java:63)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:71)
    at com.microsoft.aad.msal4j.AuthenticationResultSupplier.get(AuthenticationResultSupplier.java:20)
    at java.util.concurrent.CompletableFuture$AsyncSupply.run(CompletableFuture.java:1604)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:750)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.nimbusds.common.contenttype.ContentType
    at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:387)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:418)
    at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:352)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    ... 12 more
```

In this case the class can be found in: [content-type-2.2.jar](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/content-type)
which is a dependency of [oauth2-oidc-sdk](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.nimbusds/oauth2-oidc-sdk).

Answer (score 0):

Are you using simple Java or Spring framework for making the Microsoft SQL connection? In place of the JDBC string, set parameters in the `com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerDataSource` object.

Comment: I was using simple Java. The problem turned out to be missing dependent jars.